# Alignment points in math equation

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

I'm trying to align the following "equation":

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split} 
A_G &= [ \text{E.id, E.name, E.rank,} \\ 
& \quad \quad \text{P.rank, P.title, P.code,} \\
& \quad \quad \text{S.code, S.amount} ] \\
&= [ 1\ 1\ 1\ 1\ 1\ 1\ 1\ 1 ]
\end{split} 
\end{equation*}
```

which looks like this:

[image]

As one can see, the broken lines don't align well -- I'd like to have "P.rank" and "S.code" both left-align to "E.id". How can one achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you could use `align` to align.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A_G = [& \text{E.id, E.name, E.rank,} \\ 
&  \text{P.rank, P.title, P.code,} \\
&  \text{S.code, S.amount} ] \\
= [& 1\ 1\ 1\ 1\ 1\ 1\ 1\ 1 ]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I was trying some stuff with multiple alignment points -- all attempts failed.  In general how would multiple alignments work?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution that uses (a) a `\parbox` directive to typeset the text material -- no need to insert line breaks by hand and hence to worry about alignment points -- and (b) a `bmatrix` environment to typeset the row vector.

I chose the width of the `\textbox` -- 4cm -- so that it reproduces the number of line breaks (2) that appear in the OP's screenshot. By setting the width of the box to 5.5cm, say, the number of line breaks would be reduced from 2 to just 1.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% handy utility macro (the default width is 4cm):
\newcommand\textbox[2][4cm]{\parbox[t]{#1}{\raggedright #2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
A_G &= [\textbox{E.id, E.name, E.rank, P.rank, P.title, P.code, S.code, S.amount]} \\
    &= \begin{bmatrix}
          1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
       \end{bmatrix}
\end{split} 
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the material is textual, I suggest `tabular` (it would be `array` if the material were math); this also uses less vertical space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
A_G &= [
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    E.id, E.name, E.rank, \\
    P.rank, P.title, P.code, \\
    S.code, S.amount$]$
  \end{tabular}
\\
&= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]